# How to make image carousel work?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "fabelio" %>
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%=image_tag(user.url,:alt => "") %>
<% end %>
</figure>
</div>
<br />
<%= link_to "Add Image", new_user_path %>
```

### css for the view

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Currently it is showing 3 images one below the other and sliding it. How to show only one image and slide it. I have tried everything possible. Is there any better way to do this, without using any gem.

Comment: You are looping around users, users may have multiple user so that's  why you are getting multiple image , just use single user value from users than it will show you single image

Comment: @Akanksha, can you inspect those images and see if the images are enclosed in right `id`=slider and have figure tag around them. And also see if you are loading the styling after the images get loaded or before them.

Comment: @Akanksha, also please mention which library are you using for image slider..

Comment: @Alok how that can be done ?

Comment: you can use the value of first user from users just accessing directly via its index , or just break your current loop after first itration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the value of first user from users just accessing directly via its index , or just break your current loop after first itration.

Comment: could you let me know how this can be done, as currently doing the way you suggest is sliding only one image everytime

Answer (score 0):

You markup doesn't provide enough information but your problem seems to be with carousel than with  Rails. Try [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), it's pretty easy to use. Inside your each loop, you can create divs with image tags.

```
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="..."> <!-- Replace this with image tag -->
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```